# (F)write in a html file to the visitor's geo-coordinates using a post inside a get

Tags: php, ajax, post, get, fwrite

I'm working with the coordinates. I don't want to use a GeoIP database. So I tried first to get the coordinates, then send them with a post to a php file which write them in an html file.
This is the index.html code:

```
<p> Hello. </p>

<script type="text/javascript">

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
var ip = response.ip;
var city = response.city;
var region = response.region;
var details = JSON.stringify(response, null, 4); 

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'write.php', 
    data: '&ip='+ ip + '&city=' + city +  '&region=' + region +  '&details=' + details,
    success: function (data) {   
      alert("Sent!");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, text, error){ 
       alert("Error: not sent.");       
      }
  }); 

}, "jsonp");
```

this is the write.php code:

```
<?php 

    $ip = $_POST['ip'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $region = $_POST['region'];
    $details = $_POST['details']; 

$fh = fopen('lol.html', 'a') or die("can't open file");

fwrite($fh,'IP: $ip ;');
fwrite($fh,'Details: $details'); 

fclose($fh);

echo "Created";
?>
```

If I host and open index.html it alert "Sent!". But then, when I open lol.html I see the string: `IP: $ip ;Details: $details`

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to use variables inside single quotes `'` when writing data; so the variables aren't getting evaluated but instead being treated as literals.

So, try this instead:

```
<?php 

// Parse input
$ip      = isset($_POST['ip'])      ? $_POST['ip']      : '';
$city    = isset($_POST['city'])    ? $_POST['city']    : '';
$region  = isset($_POST['region'])  ? $_POST['region']  : '';
$details = isset($_POST['details']) ? $_POST['details'] : ''; 

// Open file for writing
$fh = @fopen('lol.html', 'a');
if (!$fh) exit('Failed to open file for writing')

// Write data
fwrite($fh, "IP: $ip\r\n");
fwrite($fh, "Details: $details"); 

// Finished
fclose($fh);
echo "Created";

?>
```

---

#### Update

Based on your comment, I have optimised this script into the following, try this out:

**index.html** (or what ever .html file)

```
<p> Hello. </p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function(response) {
    $.post('write.php', { response: JSON.stringify(response) })
    .done(function(result) {
        alert(result);
    });
});

</script>
```

**write.php**

```
<?php 

// Parse input
$response = isset($_POST['response']) ? $_POST['response'] : '';

// Decode input
$response = @json_decode($response, true);
if (!$response) {
    exit('Invalid input.');
}

// Open file for writing
$fh = @fopen('lol.html', 'a');
if (!$fh) {
    exit('Failed to open file for writing.');
}

// Write data
$result = '<pre>';
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
    $result .= "$key = $value\r\n";
}
$result .= '</pre>';
fwrite($fh, $result);

// Finished
fclose($fh);
echo "Created";

?>
```

The resulting `lol.html` file will now look like this (when `index.html` is executed):

```
<pre>ip = 90.152.2.38
hostname = host90-152-2-38.ipv4.regusnet.com
city = St Albans
region = England
country = GB
loc = 51.8379,-0.4399
org = AS8220 COLT Technology Services Group Limited
postal = AL3
</pre>
```

And if you were to open this `lol.html` file in browser, it will render like this:

[image]

Is this what you are after?

Comment: Super!!! Is there a simple way (withouth using <html><head><style> etc) to make a new line after each key/value for the $details json array?